# Total loss of information while switching between layout view and data view? Arcgis for desktop 10.5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts, save

I managed to replicate my problem doing the following:

I have my MXD in layout mode, I open it and everything is fine as long as I stick to that view. When I change to data view and close the map, when I reopen it I have lost all information in the project, both in layout anda data view.

When I say that I lost the info, I mean that the table of contents has the data frames showing but the layers are missing, except in the second data frame which is an index map.

Sometimes I get an error messsage saying : "Unable to save. Check to make sure you access to the specified file and that there is enough space on the storage device to hold your file" although the problem still happens even if I dont save it and than reopen it.

I am using a custom map template. Could it be something related to it?

I am using the default geodatabase and it has probably hundreds of files there already, since its a big project and I did´t know better at that time.

Does someone have any idea of what is happening?

This my first time working with the program, can be a really basic user error as far as I know.

Comment: Do you have two ArcMap instances open at the same time?  If so, I suspect that will be the explanation because that error suggests that you have the same map open twice at the same time.  Stick strictly to using one at a time and I think your problem will evaporate.

Comment: No, this is not the case. Any more ideas? The error info doesnt always appear, it might not be related, as far as I know...

Comment: Maybe not related but if you use the default geodatabase since a long time and with hundred of file you should compact it (ESRI advise to do it each month : http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/compact-file-and-personal-geodatabases.htm)  it may not solve your problem but who know, and it's a simple thing to try and at last you should get better performance

Comment: Thank you JT. Im gonna do that.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact version of software in use. I refuse to use the default geodatabase because it quickly becomes a junk drawer (or junk room, or junk *house*) in which you can't find anything, but are afraid to throw anything away. Note that the objects in a file geodatabase are *tables*, not "files", and tables often require active organization.

Comment: Arcgis for desktop 10.5 Vince.  Also, if I close the mxd in layout view, when i return to it its still there even if I switch between views beforehand. If I close it when in data view, when I try to reopen  it I get a blank project. Seems that the problem might be with the layout, not sure

Comment: It may be useful to know where your "default" geodatabase is located. I know ours is on our "Home" directories by default and our IT Dept. has that set up to be a network drive so they can make backups. It causes similar problems (plus what Vince said about the default gdb; I always use a project-based file gdb if I care about the result at all).